# Generating Excel file with XLConnect-Removed Feature: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)

Tags: r, excel-2007, xlconnect

I am using XLConnect in R for the purpose of daily report generation. I have a program that runs automatically at specific time to append the data for most recent date daily into an excel file (Excel 2007). The program works fine to do this task. But, sometimes when i open the excel file it says that "Excel found unreadable content. do you want to recover the content of this workbook?"
The best part of this issue is that i can't reproduce this issue again to know the exact root cause for the problem. It arises in a random manner. Because, when i try to run the program again it works fine. Can somebody help me to identify the root cause?

Comment: I had the same problem, i think it had to do something with styles, at least that's wat excel reported as broken, but i also could not reproduce the problem every time.
If you can, switch to a more current excel format and the xlsx package which is more stable. If you need to output old xls I think you're stuck with XLConnect.

Comment: I switched to xlsx package which has helped me to resolve this issue. Also, it is significantly faster compare to XLConnect. Thanks.